# How to apply ast-grep rewrite rules to a file automatically?

Tags: search, replace, command-line, abstract-syntax-tree, ast-grep

I am using [ast-grep](https://ast-grep.github.io/), a CLI tool for code structural search and rewriting, to find and replace some patterns in my code. I have written a YAML file with some rewrite rules, and I can use `sg scan` to see the matches and replacements in the terminal. However, I am not sure how to apply the changes to the original file automatically, without manually editing it.

Here is an example of my YAML file `rule.yaml`:

```yaml
id: replace-var-with-let
language: js
rule:
  pattern: var $A = $B
fix: let $A = $B
```

Here is an example of my test file `test.js`:

```js
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
var z = x + y;
console.log(z);
```

Here is the output of `sg scan`:

```bash
sg scan -r rule.yaml test.js
test.js
help[replace-var-with-let]:
@@ -0,4 +0,4 @@
1  │-var x = 10;
  1│+let x = 10
2 2│ var y = 20;
3 3│ var z = x + y;
4 4│ console.log(z);
help[replace-var-with-let]:
@@ -0,4 +0,4 @@
1 1│ var x = 10;
2  │-var y = 20;
  2│+let y = 20
3 3│ var z = x + y;
4 4│ console.log(z);
help[replace-var-with-let]:
@@ -0,4 +0,4 @@
1 1│ var x = 10;
2 2│ var y = 20;
3  │-var z = x + y;
  3│+let z = x + y
4 4│ console.log(z);
```

How can I make ast-grep modify the code file directly, so that it becomes:

```js
let x = 10;
let y = 20;
let z = x + y;
console.log(z);
```

I am using ast-grep version 0.19.0, JavaScript as the programming language, and Mac OSX as the operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ast-grep will not modify the file directly, but it will print the modified code to the terminal. You can use the `--update-all` or `-U` flag to write the changes to the file. see the [rewrite guide](https://ast-grep.github.io/guide/rewrite-code.html#using-sg-run-p-pat-rewrite). This is similar to `eslint --fix` option or `prettier -w`

Here is the command to apply the changes to the file:

```bash
$ sg scan -r rule.yaml test.js -U
# or 
$ sg scan -r rule.yaml test.js --update-all
```

For more information, you can check out the command line references

https://ast-grep.github.io/reference/cli/scan.html#u-update-all